# Jackson date deserialization wrong

Tags: date, jersey, jackson, deserialization

I've developing a Rest API and using Jackson library for Json processing.

In my POJO I've defined few java.util.Date fields and I'm parsing these dates using ObjectMapper.

Problem is that all the dates are coming as wrong.

Here is example Json data received from client:

```
{
 "Date1":"20161208 121500",
 "Date2":"20161205 131515",
 "Date3":"19830201 122718"
}
```

Here is code snippet:

```
private final SimpleDateFormat df =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMDD hhmmss");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
mapper.setDateFormat(df);
MetaData mData = null;

try {      
  mData = mapper.readValue(metaData, MetaData.class);
}
catch(JsonProcessingException jpe) {
  return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
}
```

When Date object is created, its off by few months. When I print the dates in log, I get the following:

```
Date1: 01/08/16 00:15:00 (Original date is 12/08/2016)
Date2: 01/05/16 13:15:15 (Original date is 12/05/2016)
Date3: 01/01/83 00:27:18 (Original date is 02/01/1981)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong :(

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the incorrect datetime pattern. The pattern should be yyyyMM**dd** hhmmss.

'D' for Day in year and 'd' for Day in month.